# Как получился изменяемый объект String?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Возник один вопрос. Есть условие для вводимого значения:

```
private boolean isValid() {
    String message;

    //если < 10
    if (Integer.parseInt(jtxtInput.getText()) < 10)
        message = "Минимальное значение: 10";
    else 
        return true;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, message, "Ошибка", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return false;        

}
```

Помня о том, что объекты String являются неизменяемыми, решил это проверить и инициализировал message:

```
    String message = "test";
```

Однако никакой ошибки не возникло. Вопрос, почему, ведь по сути мы получили изменяемый String?

Благодарю.

Comment: Вы не изменяли объект, вы переприсвоили переменную.

Comment: Но, говоря о переменных, мы не имеем в виду примитивы, такие как int, boolean и т.д.?

Comment: Я не понимаю, при чем здесь примитивы, но когда вы переприсваиваете переменную, содержащую примитив, вы ровно так же ничего не делаете с оригинальным значением, а просто записываете в переменную новое.

Comment: Да, я понял про что вы говорите, благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не изменили объект message, вы присвоили ему значение, неизменяемость String выражается в том, что присвоеное значение "test" нельзя изменить, отсутствуют методы для этого, можно только присвоить ссылке message новое значение, но это уже будет совершенно другой объект.
Для того чтобы message нельзя было присвоить другое значение его нужно объявить как final.

Comment: Да, полностью согласен, благодарю.